# How to use java classes within one activity?

Tags: java, android

How can you use a java class within one activity, by that I mean is having different components of that activity spread out in a bunch of java classes. I'm a little new to android and this is what I have tried so far:

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.alex.myapplication;



 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;



 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     new Something(this);


}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

***Something.java***

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;




    public class Something  {

  private Activity activity;
  private Button add,subtract,multiply,devide;
  private EditText editA, editB, editC;
  private double doubleA,doubleB,doubleC;





      public Something(Activity a){

              activity=a;
              click();

       }


       public void click(){
           editA = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
           editB = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
           editC = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
          doubleA =Double.parseDouble(editA.getText().toString());
          doubleB =Double.parseDouble(editB.getText().toString());


              add = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.add);
              subtract = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.subtract);
              multiply = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.multiply);
              devide = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.devide);

               add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                     doubleC = doubleA+doubleB;
                     String s = "" + doubleC;
                      editC.setText(s);


                   }
               });

               subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA-doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });

               multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA*doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



           devide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA/doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



       }



       }
```

So I wasn't sure why my listeners weren't working on my buttons so I tried passing the activity to the class that has the listeners added to the buttons but that didn't work in fact now my application won't even start in the emulator. All I wanted to do was have "MainActivity" handle the "Gui" and have the "Something" class handle the listeners but no matter what I do I can't seem to make them communicate with one another to form one Activity.

***LogCat***

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2071)
        at com.example.alex.myapplication.Something.click(Something.java:32)
        at com.example.alex.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run           (ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: *If it crashes, what message(s) do you get in LogCat?*

Comment: @immibis It doesn't really crash, it won't start up, it just says there was a problem and it doesn't start. By the way I appreciate you trying to help me, all I want to do is have "MainActivity" be my GUI and have "Something" handle the listeners and have them all converge into one activity but it seems impossible.

Comment: What is line 32 of Something.java?

Comment: @immibis it's "editA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know this will help someone else who encountered the same problem as me will benefit, the problem was that I needed to pass the activity into my `Something(Activity a){}` constructor and initialize everything into that. Like `Something(Activity a){

            aT1 = (EditText) a.findViewById(R.id.numberOne);
            aT2 = (EditText) a.findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);
            aT3 = (EditText) a.findViewById(R.id.result);
            add = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.add);
            subtract = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.subtract);
            multiply = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.multiply);
            devide = (Button) a.findViewById(R.id.devide);
}`

And all you need to do in main activity is pass the Activity when you make an instance/execute the code(ex: Something s = new Something(this);/new Something(this);) After you done that you can just call s.click(); and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

like a before post XD with 1 java class, call it again after pressing buttons, for example, you can have a invisible buttons, radiobuttons whatever you want invisible and just with a click it turns visible and useful for you, here i go:

First the variable which controls the activity are going to do

```
String num ="";
```

then have your buttons, i use 2 of them and the others are invisible

```
Button bn1;
Button bn2;
Button bn3;
Button bn4;
bn3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
bn4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

then the button code, depends on how many buttons you want

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new Button onclickListener(){
        public void onClick(){
            //get a default variable in this case String num
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); num="cero"; intent.putExtra("po", num);
                        CodigoPeticion=2; startActivityForResult (intent,CodigoPeticion); finish(); break;
                }
            }
        });
```

this one to get the String num:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras!= null) {
            num =extras.getString("po");
        }
```

and at last but not least this one to do someting depending the String:

```
    if (num.matches("cero")){
                //do something, enable more buttons, disable radiobuttons,
bn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(num.matches("one")){//this string is from another button
                //do something else in the same activity, as you spected enable radiobuttons, show a image, etc
bn4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                //some textview with a specific title
                TextView.setText("Something's Wrong");
            }
```

don't forget the bn3 and bn4 listeners!

hope that helps you, see ya!

Comment: I already know how to do on clicks and stuff lol, didn't really answer my question? Just want to use multiple classes within the same activity

Comment: as i posted, in the onClickListener, has the intent, which call the same activity but depending the onclick send a string which manage the "next" activty (is the same but do another thing)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should rearrange the code to have the onClickListener inside Something constructor:

Something.java

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Something {

    private Activity activity;
    private Button add, subtract, multiply, devide;
    private EditText editA, editB, editC;
    private double doubleA, doubleB, doubleC;

    public Something(Activity a) {

        activity = a;

        editA = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editB = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editC = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        add = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.add);
        subtract = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.subtract);
        multiply = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        devide = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.devide);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                click(1);

            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                click(2);

            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                click(3);
            }
        });

        devide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                click(4);
            }
        });
    }


    public void click(int calculate) {

        // assume number entered - no error
        doubleA = Double.parseDouble(editA.getText().toString());
        doubleB = Double.parseDouble(editB.getText().toString());

        switch (calculate) {

            case 1:
                doubleC = doubleA + doubleB;
                String s = "" + doubleC;
                editC.setText(s);
                break;

            case 2:
                doubleC = doubleA - doubleB;
                String s = "" + doubleC;
                editC.setText(s);
                break;

            case 3:
                doubleC = doubleA * doubleB;
                String s = "" + doubleC;
                editC.setText(s);
                break;

            case 4:
                doubleC = doubleA / doubleB;
                String s = "" + doubleC;
                editC.setText(s);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

I think the problem was putting 'click()' method inside the main constructor runs through the code once only.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your "something" class in the mainactivity.

first initialize "Something" class in the main activity by

```
Something s = new Something(MainActivity.this);
```

Than you can use every method of that class in your main Activity.Just as you wanted,like this

```
s.add.setonclicklistener(...
```

or

```
s.click();
//Just use like this.
```

Comment: I did it like you said and It didn't work? It doesn't want to start up in my emulator.