# Class won't execute properly inside main activity?

Tags: java, android

How can you use a java class within one activity, by that I mean is having different components of that activity spread out in a bunch of java classes. I'm a little new to android and this is what I have tried so far:

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.alex.myapplication;



 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;



 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     new Something(this);


}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

***Something.java***

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;




    public class Something  {

  private Activity activity;
  private Button add,subtract,multiply,devide;
  private EditText editA, editB, editC;
  private double doubleA,doubleB,doubleC;





      public Something(Activity a){

              activity=a;
              click();

       }


       public void click(){
           editA = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText);
           editB = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
           editC = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
          doubleA =Double.parseDouble(editA.getText().toString());
          doubleB =Double.parseDouble(editB.getText().toString());


              add = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.add);
              subtract = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.subtract);
              multiply = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.multiply);
              devide = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.devide);

               add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                     doubleC = doubleA+doubleB;
                     String s = "" + doubleC;
                      editC.setText(s);


                   }
               });

               subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA-doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });

               multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA*doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



           devide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {

                   doubleC = doubleA/doubleB;
                   String s = "" + doubleC;
                   editC.setText(s);


               }
           });



       }



       }
```

So I wasn't sure why my listeners weren't working on my buttons so I tried passing the activity to the class that has the listeners added to the buttons but that didn't work in fact now my application won't even start in the emulator. All I wanted to do was have "MainActivity" handle the "Gui" and have the "Something" class handle the listeners but no matter what I do I can't seem to make them communicate with one another to form one Activity.

Someone suggested to do a pass in main activity `Something s = new Something(MainActivity.this);` and call it from within main activity like this `s.click();` but that didn't work.

Comment: What is the problem? Does your application crash? If it crashes, what message(s) do you get in LogCat?

Comment: Your Something Class is using Activity calls, but you haven't extended it.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over again, but rather use [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380427/how-to-use-java-classes-within-one-activity).

Comment: @NiekHaarman I would love too, but my problem hasn't been solved yet. It would be must appreciated if you attempted to answer the question instead of stating the obvious.

Comment: @immibis Yes it does, it doesn't want to start up It's fine though, I guess I'll just have to deal with this for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android every class that extends activity just have a one xml Layout to view and handle this XML file just in it's Activities,and you can make a lot of java classes that send alot of parameter but when you want to handle XML behavioral you should do in own class that Extends Activity,so you can do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button myBtn;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  new Something(this);
  myBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

 }

 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```